# How to find a pair from set using only the second value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set, std-pair

I want to find the pair using the second element only and the first element could be anything, also all of the second elements are unique.

Code using `std::find_if` but this takes linear time

```
set<pair<int,int> > s;

s.insert(make_pair(3,1));
s.insert(make_pair(1,0));

auto it = find_if(s.begin(),s.end(),[value](const pair<int,int>& p ){ return p.second == value; });

if(it==s.end()) 
    s.insert(make_pair(1,value));
else {
    int v = it->first;
    s.erase(it);
    s.insert(make_pair(v+1,value));
}
```

I want to use `std::find` function of set so that it takes logarithmic time.

Comment: You may consider switching to boost:bimap [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html)

Comment: Your example make me thing you want a `std::map`... `m[value]++;`.

Comment: Is swapping the pairs around an option? Then you can get by with `std::set::upper_bound` and `std::set::lower_bound`.

Comment: @Jorod42 I also need to insert and keep it sorted using the first element, that's why i am using `std::set`

Comment: With your setup, it's not possible to search for second value in anything but linear time. You need to change something, for example, to swap first and second entries in pairs, use a multimap or a map of vectors, add an additional _index_ container, etc.

Comment: @Jo3kerR Then there is no solution in the standard library. Either use `boost::bimap`, or two sets, or something else.

Comment: @Botje I cannot swap the pairs. Is it possible to use `std::set::lower_bound` on the second element ?

Comment: Not possible. However, apart from other suggestions (boost::bimap, std::map, swapping values, etc) you can consider defining your own type `struct MyPair { std::pair<int, int> pair_ };` and providing `operator<` for it.

Comment: You cannot have data sorted by one variable and have logarithmic search by another. It's mathematically impossible. `boost::bimap` uses internally two maps and keeps them consistent to achieve logarithmic search both ways. And why is logarithmic search so important? Unless you are dealing with huge amounts of data, linear search in continuous containers (like `std::vector`)  is *faster* than logarithmic search in non-continuous containers (like `std::set`).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Different people mean different things by "huge".  I think of 10,000 elements as a small amount of data.  I'm guessing that you don't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data structure that do exactly what you want.

However databases do something similar.  They call it [Index Skip Scanning](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/index-skip-scanning).  To implement the same without starting from scratch, you could implement a `std::map` from the first thing in the pair to a `std::map` of the second thing in the pair.  And now a lookup of a single pair is logarithmic in time, lookup of the things with a given first entry is also logarithmic in time (though iterating through those things may be slower), and lookup of the things with the second entry is linear in the number of first values you have, times logarithmic in the number of second values that you have.

Do note that this is only worthwhile if you have a very large number of pairs, and relatively few values for the first entry in the pair.  And furthermore you are constantly changing data (so maintaining multiple indexes is a lot of overhead), and only rarely doing a lookup on the second value in the pair.  Break any of those assumptions and the overhead is not worth it.

That is a rather specific set of assumptions to satisfy.  It comes up far more often for databases than C++ programmers.  Which is why most databases support the operation, and the standard library of C++ does not.